# Using angular ionic within Nrwl NX monorepo

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, nrwl-nx

I’m trying to create an Ionic Angular project within [Nx Monorepo](https://nx.dev/angular).

I’m able to initialize it and it opens successfully in browser, but running it on an emulator or real device results in `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error

[image]

I believe it's related to some incorrect path somewhere..

### Steps to reproduce

1. create nx workspace with command:
   `npx create-nx-workspace testProject`
   (create empty project)
2. than install @nrwl/angular
   `npm install --save-dev @nrwl/angular`
3. `nx g @nrwl/angular:app mobile --routing￼`
4. `ng add @ionic/angular --project=mobile`
5. `ionic init "mobile" --type=angular`
6. `ionic integrations enable cordova –add`
7. Then run the app on emulator with `ionic cordova emulate android --project=mobile`

Here's the repository with the code sample: https://github.com/tokarkin/ionic-nx

Comment: Are you sure it's nrwl/ionic, and not your webview/brorwser? Ionic by default runs on port 8200, so you would have to access it through http://localhost:8200